# Deshabilitar selección de celdas deshabilitadas en jtable

Tags: java, jtable

Ta tengo deshabilitadas las filas que quiero, lo que sucede es que no logro deshabilitar la selección de estas, en mi *jtable*.

Aquí les dejo el código que utilizo:

```
table = new JTable(){
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        return false;
    }
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        java.awt.Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(row, 2);
        if (value.equals("true")) {
            comp.setEnabled(false);
        }  else {
            comp.setEnabled(true);
        }
        return comp;
    }
};
```

Saludos!

Comment: un poco fuera de tiempo.. espero que le sirva a alguien.
En el ejemplo, solo falta añadir estas lineas, después de inicializar la JTable: table.setColumnSelectionAllowed( false ); table.setRowSelectionAllowed( false );